# Set CalRGB when applying visual representation during pdf signing using iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I'm using iText 7 for digitally signing pdf documents.
The following code is used to apply the visual representation:

```
var vai = new VisualAppearanceImages(parameter, documentToSign, ImageScale);

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
appearance.SetPageNumber(documentToSign.SignatureField.SignaturePage);

Rectangle pr = new Rectangle(documentToSign.SignatureField.SignaturePositionX,
    documentToSign.SignatureField.SignaturePositionY, documentToSign.SignatureField.Width,
    documentToSign.SignatureField.Height);
appearance.SetPageRect(pr);
        //Set the image (jpeg)
        image = GetVisualRepresentationImage();
}

appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(image);
appearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
```

The problem is that i must sign a pdf/A1b document which doesn't have the OutputIntent set.
The signature itself is valid, but the document is no longer a valid pdf/A1b.

pdf/A analyse output from foxit phantom:

> PDF/A requires that as soon as DeviceGray, DeviceRGB or DeviceCMYK are used an OutputIntent with a destination profile must be present.

[image]

The visual representation has DeviceRGB set which then causes the problem since ContentIntent on the pdf is not set.

I guess setting CalRGB instead of DeviceRGB for the visual representation could solve this problem.

Question: Is it possible to add the visual representation and setting CalRGB instead of DeviceRGB via iText?

Comment: Have you considered adding an `OutputIntent` instead?

Comment: Alternatively, as the problem is the color space of the image you add to the signature appearance, have you considered using a bitmap image with a proper color space embedded?

Comment: I think addin the OutputIntent might not work if the pdf was already signed. I will have a look at using a bitmap with an embedded color space (I did not know this).

Comment: *"I think addin the OutputIntent might not work if the pdf was already signed."* - Have you tried? There are a number of weirdnesses in which changes of that kind are allowed and which are not...

Comment: No i did not try, but it thought it should invalidate the signature. Anyways, i'll also try this.

Comment: Note about setting the image with the color space. I use imageData.SetColorSpace(1); which sets the colorspace to gray. But now the colorspace is DeviceGray instead of CalGray which has the same problem.